# Query results into an AG-Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, graphql-js, ag-grid-react

I want to display all the users and email into an ag-grid but nothing I do seems to Work. I am using react JavaScript in order to build an admin portal.

```
import React from 'react';
import './users.css'
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
const USER_QUERY = gql`
{
    users {
      _id
        username
        email
    }
}
`;

export default function Users() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(USER_QUERY);

  if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>ERROR</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>Not found</p>;

  const [columnDefs] =[
    { field: "username" },
    { field: "email" },
  ];


  const [rowData] = data.users.map(user => {
    return (
      {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
      }
    )
  }
  );

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}>
      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong? or any fixes for this.

Comment: your `const [rowData] = ...` should just be `const rowData = ...`, and similarly for `columnDefs`. What you have put is using destructuring to set these variables to only the first element of the corresponding arrays, rather than the whole array as I think you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing [ ] from

```
const [columnDefs] =[
    { field: "username" },
    { field: "email" },
  ];

const ]rowData] = data.users.map(user => {
    return (
      {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
      }
    )
  }
  );
```

to

```
 const columnDefs =[
    { field: "username" },
    { field: "email" },
  ];


  const rowData = data.users.map(user => {
    return (
      {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
      }
    )
  }
  );
```